# moving focus to next textBox when user finishes typing text

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have 4 textBoxes.

When a user touches a textBox, i save the current text aside int `tmpText`

and set the new text to empty string.

The user then type a new text.

If the user hadn't typed anything, I re-fill the textBox with `tmpText`.

If the user typed the max text length, the focus moves to the next textBox (using `watchText` delegate).

The problem is in a scenario where the user clicks a textBox, and types nothing

and press on another textBox (not the following one).

The the text is saved in `tmpText` and then re-fills the textBox.

So the system moves the focus to the next box

and there is focus on two textBoxes.

I would have used a flag `isRestoredData` to differentiate this scenario and not move the focus to the next textBox.

But the override signature doesn't allow that:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence seq, int start, int before, int count) {
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

for the TextBox, it will show Next option on the Android Keyboard and will help you to move to next TextBox.

Comment: I think this will work only if the android:singleLine="true" is set

Comment: @MasterJ my application crashes. I guess this is because android doesn't know which field is next.

Comment: If you are using this TextBox in a List then it should work to move you on.